# Reset form state from redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I currently have the following component, for simplicity, I created a minimal example on **codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ypppjk1mm9)**. It demonstrates my issue.

For stackoverflow, here's some snippets:

```
class CommentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      comment: ""
    };

    this.handleCommentChange = this.handleCommentChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleCommentChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ comment: evt.target.value });
  }

  handleFormSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.props.addComment(this.state.comment);
  }
  render() {
    const { submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <textarea
            name="comment"
            placeholder="Write your comment here..."
            rows="5"
            value={this.state.comments}
            onChange={this.handleCommentChange}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            type="submit"
            disabled={submitting}
            value="COMMENT"
          />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

My problem: How do I reset the form state (`this.state.comments = ''`), when my saga dispatches the action `COMMENT_ADD_SUCCESS`?

What I'd like to avoid: Adding comment in the redux state. I understand that I can move comments into the redux store, and return something like `{...state, commentField: ''}` in the reducer itself.

This form is simple for demonstration purposes, but I have a much more complex form, which I feel doesn't need to be added to the redux store, as it's state is short lived, and once the component dies, the state can simply be discarded. Additionally, if I need to add comment to the store, I need to create actions like `COMMENT_UPDATED`, which update the redux store, and this can be a rather big hassle, especially with forms with a lot of fields.

Comment: Do you not want to add `this.setState({ comment: '' })` in your `handleFormSubmit`?

Comment: why you don't pass a callback to the addComment action: ```this.props.addComment(this.state.comment, callback);``` where that callback is a member in the CommentForm that resets the comment state ? when the adding succeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually pass a callback as extra param to the action, and invoke the callback from the saga. So I would change your `CommentForm` code to dispatch the action passing an object with text value and callback function:

```
handleFormSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.props.addComment({ comment: this.state.comment, callback: function() {
      alert("callback invoked");
      // here do cleanup of state as you wish
    }});
  }
```

and change the saga to invoke the callback on success:

```
function* addComment(params) {
  console.log("Adding Comment");

  yield put({ type: "ADD_COMMENT_FETCHING" });

  // Simulate call success
  yield call(delay, 5000);

  alert("(From saga) The comment was added successfully.");
  yield put({ type: "ADD_COMMENT_SUCCESS" });

  params.action.callback(); // <--- here the callback
}
```

Redux state is untouched, and you can also think of adding a second callback which will be invoked in case of failure/error within the saga.
I forked your sandbox, you can check the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/krqv5lnzr)

Comment: Nice! Did not even think about adding a callback.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work since you're providing the `submitting` prop. What you want to do is capture the transition from true to false.

```js
  componentDidUpdate( prevProps ) {
    
    if ( prevProps.submitting === this.props.submitting ) {
      // The state of our comment submission hasn't changed so do nothing.
      return;
    }

    if ( ! this.props.submitting ) {
      // The comment just finished submitting because we
      // we went from true to false
      this.setState( { comments: '' } );
    }

    
  }
```

Comment: Eslint is yelling at me, that I should avoid `setState()` in `componentDidUpdate()`: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-update-set-state.md (But this is a handy thing to know, and def an alternative way!)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
  handleFormSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.props.addComment(this.state.comment);
    this.setState({ comments: ''});
  }
```

To expand on what @Lefi said:

You could add a callback and call it within your saga.js.

```
callback = () => {
  this.setState({ comments : '' })
}

handleFormSubmit(comment, callback) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That resets the form immediately, not when the server returns back a response. If there is an error, I don't want to reset the form.